# Unzip or inflate php://input stream?

Tags: php, input, stream, unzip, inflate

I'm trying to unzip a zip file directly from the `php://input` stream.  I'm running Laravel Homestead, `PHP 7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1`, with an endpoint at `myproject.app/upload`, here is the `curl` command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'http://myproject.app/upload' \
  --data-binary "@myfile.zip" \
```

Here is a list of all the methods I've tried, which all fail:

---

```
dd(file_get_contents('compress.zlib://php://input'));
```

*file_get_contents(): cannot represent a stream of type Input as a File Descriptor*

---

```
$fh = fopen('php://input', 'rb');

stream_filter_append($fh, 'zlib.inflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ, array('window'=>15));

$data = '';

while (!feof($fh)) {
    $data .= fread($fh, 8192);
}

dd($data);
```

*""*

---

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

$zip->open('php://input');
$zip->extractTo(storage_path() . '/' . 'myfile');
$zip->close();
```

*ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object*

Here are all the links I've found on the subject:

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php#83220

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php#109657

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php#118461

https://secure.phabricator.com/rP42566379dc3c4fd01a73067215da4a7ca18f9c17

https://arjunphp.com/how-to-unpack-a-zip-file-using-php/

I'm beginning to think that it's not possible to operate on streams with PHP's built-in zip functionality.  The overhead and complexity of writing temporary files would be pretty disappointing.  Does anyone know how to do this, or is it a bug?

Comment: Use phar:// for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878849/606859

Answer (score 7):

After more research, I discovered the answer, but it's not satisfactory.  Due to one of the great blunders of the modern world, **gzip and zip are not the same format**.  gzip encodes a single file (that's why we often see tar.gz), while zip encodes files and folders.  I was trying to upload a zip file and decode it with gzip, which doesn't work.  More info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/539149

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579506/539149

The other part of this issue is that **PHP neglected to provide a stream filter for gzip**:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926679/539149

So even though `gzopen('php://temp', 'rb')` works, `gzopen('php://input', 'rb')` **does not** because the input stream is not rewindable.  This makes it impossible to operate on an in-memory stream, because there is no way to write data to a stream and then read unzipped data on a separate gzip connection to that stream.  Which means the following code **does not** work:

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$temp = fopen("php://temp", "rb+");
stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
rewind($temp);
dd(stream_get_contents(gzopen('php://temp', 'rb')));
```

People have attempted various workarounds, but they all do bit fiddling:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php#105676

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php#112200

I did manage to get a pure in-memory solution to work, but since it's not possible to use streams, a needless copy occurs:

```
// works (stream + string)
dd(gzdecode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

```
// works (stream + file)
dd(stream_get_contents(gzopen(storage_path() . '/' . 'myfile.gz', 'rb')));

// works (stream + file)
dd(file_get_contents('compress.zlib://' . storage_path() . '/' . 'myfile.gz'));
```

```
// doesn't work (stream)
dd(stream_get_contents(gzopen('php://input', 'rb')));

// doesn't work (stream + filter)
dd(file_get_contents('compress.zlib://php://input'));
```

Without a working example, I have to assume that **PHP's zip implementation is incomplete because it can't operate on streams**.  If anyone has more information, I'm happy to revisit this.  Please post any examples or repositories that implement zipped uploads/downloads via streams, thanks!